Full wave bridge rectifier with Pi or T filter simulation won't converge
I'm designing a full wave bridge rectifier and want to compare a pi filter and T filter after the rectification.  I intend to add a transformer at the input and a buck-boost converter on the output. However, I can't seem to get the rectifier with the filter to converge!  I've tried the different convergence techniques (https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F), different ground connections, different source resistances, and different diodes.  I would like to use my own diodes that I added for a more accurate simulation.  But for some reason they won't converge with the T filter I have.
To get something to converge I make cshunt=1e-15 and use LTSpice's ideal diodes.  I'm hesitant that that is just disguising a larger problem with my model that I'm missing though.  I don't completely understand the cshunt's use.  I've also read in these forums that there can be some resonance issues with diodes when they switch from on to off.  But I don't understand it either or how to fix it.  The results of my T filter with ideal diodes and cshunt seem "too perfect" to be reasonable.
Can someone help me get my T filter to work with non-ideal diodes?  And explain if adding cshunt is a realist representation of my model?  Also whether or not I need to have the 100k resistor to ground?



Good question. I have learned a few things (epsilon and revepsilon, by themselves, can't remedy the issue.) I also finally got a moment to add some documentation on the behavioral diode and to try some alternatives that have already been suggested here.
First off, just moving the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ from \$V_1\$ supply to your negative rail solves the problem.

I moved the resistor back to where you have it, added epsilon and revepsilon values to the behavioral diode model, and then tried the alternate solver and got this:

If I go back to the normal solver, the above just gets locked up again.
So the particular location you chose for floating the circuit is causing trouble.
Returning to the earlier schematic with the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ moved back to the negative rail and using the alternate solver instead of the normal solver gets similar results. So this change seems to be working regardless of using the normal or alternate solvers.
A difference may be that where you floated the circuit was between the anode and cathode connections of two diodes and the new location is at a junction of two anodes. The diodes may be causing some trouble. The alternate solver, with the addition of epsilon into the mix, produces "something" even though not terribly useful.
Regardless, I don't know the exact problem. Either placement of the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor would have no current through it and, in effect, would isolate ground. I may expect a singularity problem. But it is going undetected, if so.
This suggests another test. I'll replace the resistor with a \$0\:\text{A}\$ current source to ground:

I think the fact that the solver specifically identifies the neg rail node here is significant and may suggest why placing the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ resistor on this node allows the solver to function.
The diode model you chose is a special behavioral model. It's not the Shockley diode model. I think for the future, you may want to include epsilon and revepsilon since you using that diode model type. These factors soften up the diode model.
Start with this piecewise starting point:

It's very sharp! And this can be very bad for simulation.
Here's an example of what happens when using epsilon and revepsilon:

You can now see the softened corners. This is makes simulation easier.
With that in mind, let's run your circuit but with the negative rail grounded (same result using the \$100\:\text{k}\Omega\$):

And that looks about the same as the first run. So grounding or floating works in this case. And using epsilon and revepsilon won't harm your simulation results and may help avoid some problems later on. But you will need to work out appropriate values for them.

Thank you very much for such a thorough analysis and explanation!  That was all very helpful!  Moving the ground around solved my problem and the rest of the information was very useful too!

You need to ground your output (bottom of R1/R3). Perhaps increase R6/R7 depending on how much you can leak there.
With your entire circuit “floating” with 100 kΩ to ground, it’s no wonder it struggles to converge.

You're using a default diode model, which probably has too low IS to resolve the singular matrix you've created.
Note that there is only one ground reference in the circuit, through a large resistor at that; after the rectifier, any time diodes are not conducting, the "DC" side is floating and an unambiguous solution cannot be calculated.  This usually results in a singular matrix error -- though the solution may continue instead, albeit at a pathetic pace as good as stuck.
To solve this, use a more realistic model.  The PMEG3050 model is available from the manufacturer here: 
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/spice-model/PMEG3050EP.txt 
Notice IS is fairly high, and a shunt resistor is provided besides.  As well as the capacitance, this will define the node voltages when reverse-biased.
You may also find it worthwhile to float the AC source and ground the DC side, or use two 100k resistors, or set the RSHUNT parameter to a modest value (perhaps 1e8 or so).  Finally, remember to measure the voltage difference when plotting input or output voltages, any time the reference is not also ground.

Thank you for pointing me to the model!  Total oversight on my part to not look at the manufactures website facepalm
